# How to set user control visibility, upon user role

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, user-controls

I want to implement access control for usercontrols depending on user role(s), I want to do it on the control base class, in such way that on every user control I only need to set a string with allowed roles to see the user control

This is how an user control class may look like:

```
public partial class SimpleMenu : MyUsrControlBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          AlloweRoles = "RoleA, RoleB"
          //specific user control functionality
        }
    }
```

The base class:

```
 public abstract class MyUsrControlBase : UserControl
    {
        private string _allowedRoles;

        protected internal string AllowedRoles
        {
            set
            {
                _allowedRoles = value;
                ValidateRoles();
            }
        }

        private ValidateRoles()
        {
            //Role validation logic

            if (RoleHasAccess)
               {
               // Set user control visibility to true        
               }
           else
               {
               // Set user control visibility to false        
               }
        }
    }
```

How to set up user control visibility from the base class depending on the validation result?

Also which event in the user control is the best to set the roles?

```
AlloweRoles = "RoleA, RoleB"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the inherited [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx) property from the base class:

```
private void ValidateRoles()
{
    // Role validation logic.

    Visible = RoleHasAccess;
}
```

**EDIT:** Concerning your second question, you can initialize the `AllowedRoles` property in the derived class' constructor, so it will be set for the whole lifespan of the user control:

```
public partial class SimpleMenu : MyUserControlBase
{
    public SimpleMenu()
    {
        AllowedRoles = "RoleA, RoleB";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Frederic, I only had to put the AllowedRoles = ".." in the OnLoad event of the control because Session vars are needed to get the roles